# How do you configure an environment for an open source project from sourceforge

Tags: java, eclipse, open-source, development-environment

After some forum conversations I'd like to try correcting some open source code on a project (DataNucleus) based in SourceForge.

Everything is configured like most other open source projects there as far as it appears to me.

My goal is to **configure the environment** so I can **run the test cases** they have created for the project.

I've never tried to configure an environment from one of these sources and don't know where to start really. I have a command line SVN client (but no honest experience with SVN either).

I see a lot of projects in there. Test cases appear to be separate projects. It's not clear how dependencies and such work.

I would think that these projects are set up so that creating a local environment of the project is, for the most part, straight forward.

Which leads me to believe that I just don't know how that's done, properly.

**If someone's done this, could you give me a bullet point list of things I need to do to set up a typical environment off of sourceforge?**

Comment: Yes, I don't need a novel, just a starting point and some guidelines so I know I'm working myself in the right direction.

Comment: I would check for a README or similar documentation in the project files itself. Unfortunately, there isn't going to be any generic documentation that will be able to help you with a specific project, since every project is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A forum post on DataNucleus site answered this, there is complete documentation on setting up a development environment available on their site that I hadn't come across yet:

http://www.datanucleus.org/development/index.html